# Can a github read only user be able to compare code if I send them a pull request with new code?

Tags: git, github

So I'm thinking if the read-only user creates a fork of my project and I send them a pull request, they should be able to compare it with what they originally had, correct?

If not, what is the best way to allow a read-only user to see the most recent changes on an issue/ticket?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can. Also, you can give a PR from another branch to your main branch (in your own repo), and if someone have read access to your repo (everyone have read access on public repos) they can see the changes even without forking the repo.

So if all you want is someone to be able to do the code review, just give them read access to your repo, and make a PR to your own repo.